Unable to authenticate users based on their roles using session management via Node
I have a single form that I want to authenticate users (doctors, patients, and admins). I am using Node for the backend and MySQL for the database.
Backend Server setup:
// import neccessary packages
const db = require('./config/db') // database conn
const express = require('express') // web server
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') // capture form data
const session = require('express-session');  // session-management
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session); // session-management storage
require('dotenv').config() // manage environment variables
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

// middleware
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:5500', 'http://localhost:5500'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'], 
    credentials: true 
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.html')))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // capture form data

// sesssion store
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore({}, db)

// configure session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 // 1 hour
    }
}))

// routes
app.use('/telemedicine/api/patients', require('./routes/patientRoutes'))
app.use('/telemedicine/api/providers', require('./routes/providerRoutes.js'))
app.use('/telemedicine/api/admin', require('./routes/adminRoutes.js'))

// fetch for the html file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/', 'index.html'))
})

// Patient Dashboard
app.get('/dashoard', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/patient', 'dashboard.html'))
})

// Provider Dashboard
app.get('/dashoard', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/doctor', 'dashboard.html'))
})

// Admin Dashboard
app.get('/dashoard', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/admin', 'dashboard.html'))
})

const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 3200

// start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})

I tried to use one API for my form to authenticate the user
register.html:
<div class="container register">
      <div class="form__image register__image">
        <img src="images/register.png" alt="registerImage" />
      </div>
      <div class="form__container">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <form id="registerForm" method="POST" action="/register">
          <!-- Role Selection -->
          <div>
            <p>Select type of account</p>
            <div id="role-selection" class="selection">
              <span data-role="patient">Patient</span>
              <span data-role="provider">Doctor</span>
              <span data-role="admin">Admin</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Form -->
          <div class="form__field">
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="first_name"
                name="first_name"
                placeholder="First Name"
                required
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                id="last_name"
                name="last_name"
                placeholder="Last Name"
                required
              />
              <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                required
              />
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <!-- Dynamic Fields based on Role -->
            <div
              id="patient-fields"
              class="role-specific-fields"
              style="display: none"
            >
              <input
                type="date"
                id="date_of_birth"
                name="date_of_birth"
                placeholder="Date of Birth"
                required
              />
              <div>
                <select id="language" name="language" required>
                  <option value="">Select Language</option>
                  <option value="English">English</option>
                  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                  <option value="French">French</option>
                </select>
                <select id="gender" name="gender" required>
                  <option value="">Select Gender</option>
                  <option value="Male">Male</option>
                  <option value="Female">Female</option>
                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div
              id="provider-fields"
              class="role-specific-fields"
              style="display: none"
            >
              <input
                type="text"
                id="specialty"
                name="specialty"
                placeholder="Specialty"
                required
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                id="phone_number"
                name="phone_number"
                placeholder="Phone Number"
                required
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <p>Already have an account ? <a href="login.html">Login</a></p>

          <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="message" style="display: none"></div>
    </div>

register.js:
// Role Selecetion
document.querySelectorAll('#role-selection span').forEach((span) => {
  span.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const selectedRole = this.getAttribute('data-role');

    document.querySelectorAll('#role-selection span').forEach(s => s.classList.remove('selected'));

    this.classList.add('selected');

    const patientFields = document.getElementById('patient-fields');
    const providerFields = document.getElementById('provider-fields');

    patientFields.style.display = 'none';
    providerFields.style.display = 'none';

    // Reset required fields
    const allRequiredFields = document.querySelectorAll('input[required], select[required]');
    allRequiredFields.forEach(field => field.removeAttribute('required'));

    if (selectedRole === 'patient') {
      patientFields.style.display = 'flex';
      patientFields.querySelectorAll('input, select').forEach(field => field.setAttribute('required', true));
    } else if (selectedRole === 'provider') {
      providerFields.style.display = 'flex';
      providerFields.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(field => field.setAttribute('required', true));
    }

    document.getElementById('role-selection').setAttribute('data-selected-role', selectedRole);
  });
});


// Handle Register
document.getElementById('registerForm').addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const role = document.getElementById('role-selection').getAttribute('data-selected-role');
  const first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
  const last_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  let date_of_birth = document.getElementById('date_of_birth') ? document.getElementById('date_of_birth').value : '';
  let language = document.getElementById('language') ? document.getElementById('language').value : '';
  let gender = document.getElementById('gender') ? document.getElementById('gender').value : '';
  let specialty = document.getElementById('specialty') ? document.getElementById('specialty').value : '';

  if (!role) {
    return alert('Please select a role.');
  }

  if (!first_name || !last_name || !email || !password) {
    return alert('Please fill in all required fields.');
  }

  if (role === 'patient' && (!date_of_birth || !language || !gender)) {
    return alert('Please fill in all patient-specific fields.');
  }

  if (role === 'provider' && !specialty) {
    return alert('Please provide your specialty.');
  }

  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3200/telemedicine/api/patients/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ first_name, last_name, email, password, role, date_of_birth, language, gender, specialty }),
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  if (response.ok) {
    alert('Registration successful!');
    window.location.href = '/login'; 
  } else {
    alert(data.message);  
  }
});



The user should be authenticated based on their role, then they should be redirected to their respective routes. However When I try to login or register, this is what I am getting
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
register.js:67 
        
        
       POST http://localhost:3200/telemedicine/api/patients/register net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

